# Inserting @OneToMany relation object with child not inserting parent id in child table?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jpa

I have two model class Gizmo and GizmoChild. I am saving a gizmo object with having gizmoChild object. Gizmo object is saving properly but in the GimoChild table gizmo id is NULL.

Gizmo Model:

```
  @Entity
  public class Gizmo {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long Id;
    private String field1;
    private String field2;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "gizmo", fetch = 
    FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<GizmoChild> children;
 }
```

GizmoChild Model:

```
@Entity 
public class GizmoChild {
 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
 private Long Id;
 private String childField1;
 private String childField2;
 @ManyToOne
 private Gizmo gizmo;
}
```

GimoRepository:

```
@Repository
public interface GizmoRepository extends JpaRepository<Gizmo, Long> {
}
```

GizmoService:

```
@Service
public class GizmoService {

@Autowired
 private GizmoRepository gizmoRepository;

 public void save(Gizmo gizmo){
    gizmoRepository.save(gizmo);
}
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveGizmo(Model model){
    Gizmo gizmo1 = new Gizmo();
    gizmo1.setField1("Field1");
    gizmo1.setField2("Field2");

    GizmoChild gizmoChild = new GizmoChild();
    gizmoChild.setChildField1("ChildField1");
    gizmoChild.setChildField2("ChildField2");

    gizmo1.getChildren().add(gizmoChild);

    gizmoService.save(gizmo1);
    return "redirect:/";
}
```

I am creating a Gizmo object than i'm creating GizmoChild and adding them on list. Gizmo is saving but GizmoChild table gizmo id is not inserting. How to get rid of this problem?

Comment: @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST) by dfault OneToMany is LAZY, also you can put  private List<GizmoChild> children = new ArrayList<>(); , let me know if this fixes your issue.

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't fix the issue. It's still inserting null.

Comment: Ok, I created an answer for it

Comment: Look this link: https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you can add GizmoChildRepository too, cause of Gizmo and GizmoChild are different entity object of yours:

```
@Repository
public interface GizmoChildRepository extends JpaRepository<GizmoChild, Long> {
}
```

Then changing service method `save(Gizmo gizmo)` for persisting GizmoChild data too.

GizmoService:

```
@Service
public class GizmoService {

@Autowired
private GizmoRepository gizmoRepository;

@Autowired
private GizmoChildRepository gizmoChildRepository;

public void save(Gizmo gizmo) {
   for(GizmoChild child : gizmo.getChildren()) {
       gizmoChildRepository.save(child);
   }
   gizmoRepository.save(gizmo);
}
```

Comment: It doesn't fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="gizmo")
private Set<GizmoChild> workOrders;

@ManyToOne(optional=false)
@JoinColumn(name="gizmo_id", referencedColumnName="id")
private Gizmo gizmo;
```

Comment: It doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: if you put it as EAGER, so that you can be persisted stronger.

Comment: could you please provide your code on some repo? I wanna try it, or you can create a poc about it, thanks..